# Selecting a Semantic UI dropdown item with Protractor

Tags: protractor, semantic-ui

I have a Semantic UI defined like that:

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown" id="my_dropdown">
    <input name="gender" type="hidden">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Gender</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I'm initializing it by using `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();`.

Now when I want to test this dropdown from my end-to-end tests which I run with Protractor it doesn't allow me to select it, I do:

```
element(by.id('my_dropdown')).click().then(function() {
    element.all(by.css('#my_dropdown option')).then(function(options) {
        options[1].click();
    });
});
```

And it fails with: `Failed: element not visible`.

How can I select my dropdown value?

Answer (score 0):

Semantic UI hides the `<select>`, and the `<option>`'s which are contained in it, and replaces them with nicer looking `<div>`'s. Hence Protractor and the underlying webdriver correctly discover that the elements are hidden. The clean way with a promise doesn't work here, we have to select them via Semantic UI, i.e. we have to execute some JS inside our Protractor spec like this:

```
browser.executeScript('$("#my_dropwdown").dropdown("set selected", "1")');
```

This selects the `<option>` with the `data-value` 1.